# initial Connection to Mysql is slow

Tags: mysql, performance

My intial connection time from my azure IIS server to my VM having mysql is

```
Connection time: 0.04
```

However subsequent connection times are well under 0.01

```
Connection time: 0.01
```

I dont think this is an IIS problem since the same code works for connecting to cleardb servers well within 0.01 seconds.

The 0.04 initial slow connection seems to happen only on my hosted VM using mysql community server
Below is a simple PHP code for testing connection time.

```
 $time_start = microtime(true); 
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
    echo 'Connection time: ' . $execution_time ;
```

I also tried mysqld: skip-name-resolve. and restarted mysql (also vm too) But no luck. Please suggest. Thank you!

-- More --

I also noticed initial 0.04 connection time reduces to 0.01 for subsequent requests if they are couple of seconds apart. However, if I delay my request for another 60 seconds, I hit 0.04 connection time again.

Comment: The duplicate doesnt help. updating with PHP code. thanks

Comment: Is it really a problem or just a curiosity?

Comment: Yes! That is a rough 300% improved connection time

Comment: But it is 40 vs. 10 ms, so it can be essentially anything... maybe an expired name server entry or such

Comment: IMHO 0.01 seconds is still rather slow (0.003s on my Linux box). Most likely the difference is a firewall/router in the middle.

Comment: Amy mean to trace time. Like processing time vs network transit time